Why is my nextflow script executed sequentially?
I have the following Nextflow script:
nextflow.enable.dsl=2
include { check_folders; downloadClinvar; downloadReferenceGenome; downloadBedFiles; downloadGatkVcfFiles } from '/home/user/Desktop/pipeline/download_data.nf'
workflow {
    check_folders()
    downloadClinvar(check_folders.out)
    downloadReferenceGenome(check_folders.out)
    downloadBedFiles(check_folders.out)
    downloadGatkVcfFiles(check_folders.out)
}

The graph that is generated for me using the -preview -with-dag flags is the following:

When I run the workflow it works fine but it performs each step sequentially, and I want it to download everything at the same time.
What could be happening to me? Why is my nextflow script executed sequentially?

Cross-postd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78445082/why-is-my-nextflow-script-executed-sequentially

Does the machine you run on have sufficient resources to run these processes in parallell?

Yes Pallie, I have Intel i8 7th generation, with 16GB of RAM

If your processes request a large amount of RAM/processors per process, that still could be the reason you're not getting parallellised processes
